# How to make json format in ASP.NET Web API 2 to become vertical

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an ASP.NET Web API 2 and I tried to show data in json format, it shows in horizontal way and it look like this in google chrome. I want to make it in the expect format.

Below error is what I get in the Google chrome:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. [{"UserId":23,"Name":"Emily","Access":3,"Mobile":"07419231"},{"UserId":31,"Name":"Lydia","Access":5,"Mobile":"67567587"},{"UserId":45,"Name":"Peter","Access":1,"Mobile":"90345853"},{"UserId":56,"Name":"Lebron","Access":4,"Mobile":"43895449"},{"UserId":73,"Name":"Amber","Access":0,"Mobile":"45788477"}]

What I expect is something like this format in below:

```
[
    {
        "UserId":23,
        "Name":"Emily",
        "Access":3,
        "Mobile":"07419231"
    },
    {
        "UserId":31,
        "Name":"Lydia",
        "Access":5,
        "Mobile":"67567587"
    },
    {
        "UserId":45,
        "Name":"Peter",
        "Access":1,
        "Mobile":"90345853"
    },
    {
        "UserId":56,
        "Name":"Lebron",
        "Access":4,
        "Mobile":"43895449"
    },
    {
        "UserId":73,
        "Name":"Amber",
        "Access":0,
        "Mobile":
        "45788477"
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ApiTesting.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=DESKTOP-US2AF5N; database=Test; integrated security=true;");

        public string Get()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From TblDraft", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                return "No Data Found";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify the `Formatting` parameter, like so: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject( dt, Formatting.Indented );`

Comment: I have tried that Formatting.Indented already, I don’t know is the chrome problem or my code have problem

Comment: Have you opened the output JSON file in a proper text editor (rather than a web-browser)?

Comment: I will try it out first and how do I output json file in proper text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you serialize an c# object using Newtonsoft.Json you have to add a formatting option if you want to get an intented string

```
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: It doesn’t work on Google chrome, I have tried it before

Comment: @user19613128 I always use Chrome and newer have any problems. You have to deside what do you really need and what for.

Comment: i just want to make the format become a better way to look at the api, because i have 1000 records to look at in my work

Comment: @user19613128 You can install Chrome extensions to auto format the JSON response... Ideally, your API returns machine readable data, not human readable. If you indent the response from the API, it slows it down for large response bodies

Comment: it needs to put it in webapiconfig to make it works